# Which tokenizer to use for the Brown tagset?

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm designing a POS tagger to tag words using the Brown tags. First, I need to split the input sentence into tokens. NLTK has numerous word tokenizers. Which one should I use to tag the words using Brown tags?

Comment: I don't think the tagset is important for the choice of the tokeniser. The important thing to know is what tokeniser was used in the *training data* (the annotated corpus) you are going to use. Usually, the documentation of a corpus includes this information. You should definitely use the same when predicting tags.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it